# How to log hibernate native SQL instead of HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to log native SQL instead of HQL ? I don't have source code but i add log4j  commands to get SQL in log file. I enabled below two lines of code logging in configuration file.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

But still i want to see as native SQL instead of HQL. I can add only log4j commands to see the SQL.

Is there any commands to help to get native SQL queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following in log4j configuration file

```
# enables logs for SQL DML statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 

# enables logs for JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Still it logs SQL objects only not Native SQL. I want to see SQL format "select name, address from employee". Is it possible ?